# What's the best way to do an IK rig for a stick figure?

Tags: rigging

This is the tutorial I used for learning IK rigging. https://youtu.be/Q9f-WVs3ghI It's difficult to do this kind of rigging with stick figure legs, since they don't have feet and their legs are really close together in a t-pose. Is there a recommended way of rigging stick figure legs with inverse kinematics?

Answer (score 1):

If you struggled with that tutorial, you might have a hard time with Rigify too, idk (Rigify is worth learning though, imo).  But Blender has a built in *Auto IK Feature*; so you just add some bones, parent your mesh to the armature, then turn on the check box for "auto IK".  You need to be in **Pose Mode** to see the option in the tools area, where ever the heck that is now, lol.  GL OP  (tools is the screwdriver/wrench icon in the properties panel, I think)

Answer (score 0):

Using Addon "Rigify" might be the best way

It includes auto IK function,so you don't need to set the bones one by one

Answer (score 0):

If you have legs without feet you can simply do it this way:

- Create your torso, thigh and shin, parent the thigh to the torso (*Keep Offset* mode)
- Create a target bone and a pole target bone, deparent them from the other bones, deactivate their *Deform* option.
- Give the shin an *IK* constraint, with the target bone as *Target* and with the pole target bone as *Pole Target*.
- If the shin bone rotates abnormally once in *Pose* mode, correct its *Pole Angle* in the constraint.
- To mirror the bones, select all in Edit mode and go in the *Armature* menu (3D view bottom menu bar) > *Symmetrize*.
- For the mesh parentage, if it doesn't work correctly *With Automatic Weight*, parent *With Empty Groups*, and assign the group to the vertices you want in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*, or switch your armature to *Pose* mode, switch your mesh to *Weight Paint* mode, and begin to paint for each bone.

[image]